# Using an Alias in SQL Calculations

Tags: mysql, sql, database, syntax

Why won't this query work?

```
SELECT 10 AS my_num, my_num*5 AS another_number
FROM table
```

In this example, I'm trying to use the my_num alias in other calculations.  This results in unknown column "my_num"

This is a simplified version of what I am trying to do, but basically I would like to use an alias to make other calculations.  My calculations are much more complicated and thats why it would be nice to alias it since I repeat it several times different ways.

Answer (score 197, accepted):

Simply wrap your reused alias with `(SELECT alias)` :

```
SELECT 10 AS my_num, 
       (SELECT my_num) * 5 AS another_number
FROM table
```

Comment: I am wondering where that functionality is documented. I've searched in the whole MySQL documentation and I have not found it. I don't know how this "alias reusing" works and I am curious about portability or performance impact. If someone knows more about this I will appreciate a link. Thanks you.

Comment: this just made my week.. maybe month.  super useful especially with aliases built from flow control statements like `IF()`, `CASE()`, etc

Comment: @CarlosGant: The `(SELECT alias)` part is treated as a "dependent subquery", at least according to MySQL's `EXPLAIN` and Visual Explain functions.

Comment: Nevermind, it didn't work for me.  I got "unknown column".

Comment: `SELECT kabupaten.nama AS kabupaten, kecamatan.nama AS kecamatan,
 SUM(pihaks.luas) AS target_luas, SUM(realisasi.luas) AS realisasi_luas,
 SELECT(realisasi_luas)/SELECT(target_luas)*100 AS persentase_luas`. Tried like this but not working

Comment: This doesn't work for me if I try to use `SELECT` multiple times. `SELECT Users.Id, SUM(Posts.Score) AS ScoreSum, SUM(Posts.ViewCount) AS ViewSum, (SELECT(ViewSum) / SELECT(ScoreSum)) AS ViewScoreRatio` says "Incorrect syntax near SELECT" for the second `SELECT`.

Comment: In terms of portability this does not appear to work in postgresql 14

Answer (score 11):

You'll need to use a subselect to use that aliases that way

```
SELECT my_num*5 AS another_number FROM
(
    SELECT 10 AS my_num FROM table
) x
```

Comment: @RyanHeneise, it's a subselect alias; that way you could go with `x.my_num`

Answer (score 6):

Aliases in sql are not like variables in a programming language.  Aliases can only be referenced again at certain points (particularly in `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses).  But you can't reuse an alias in the `SELECT` clause.  So you can use a derived query (such as suggested by [Rubens Farias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077475/using-an-alias-in-sql-calculations/2077483#2077483)) which lets you basically rename your columns and/or name any computed columns.

Or you could use a `VIEW` if your formulas are generally fixed

```
CREATE VIEW table10 AS SELECT 10 AS my_num FROM table;
SELECT my_num * 5 AS another_number FROM table10;
```

I believe that will be slightly faster than using a derived query but it probably depends a lot on your real query.

Or you could just duplicate the work:

```
SELECT 10 AS my_num, 10 * 5 AS another_number FROM table;
```

Which might be convenient in something like php/perl:

```
my $my_num = 10;
my $query = "SELECT $my_num AS my_num, $my_num * 5 AS another_number FROM table";
```

Answer (score 0):

``**Another option is to use the APPLY operator**

```
SELECT my_num, my_num*5 AS another_number
FROM table
CROSS APPLY 
(SELECT 5 AS my_num) X
```

Comment: Note that `CROSS APPLY` does not appear to be available in MySQL *(yet)*.

Answer (score 0):

Easy peasy. You can use variables.

```
SELECT @my_num := 10 AS my_num, @my_num*5 AS another_number;
SHOW WARNINGS;
```

This will throw a warning: "Setting user variables within expressions is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Consider alternatives: 'SET variable=expression, ...', or 'SELECT expression(s) INTO variables(s)'."