# How to alias a field or column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, subquery, alias

I'm trying to do something like this. But I get an unknown column error:

```
SELECT SUM(field1 + field2) AS col1, col1 + field3 AS col3 from core
```

Basically, I want to just use the alias so that I won't need to perform the operations performed earlier. Is this possible in mysql?

Comment: typo, its supposed to be col1

Comment: why you yous `col1` in `select` when `col1` is already an alias

Comment: a field in the table with integer datatype, field1 and field2, and the alias col1 are integer as well.

Comment: what is the problem in `SELECT SUM(field1 + field2 + field3) AS coll from core`

Comment: @diEcho: I just want to reuse something that has already been computed earlier

Comment: I think I'll just do the computation in php if this is not possible. Thanks for those who commented.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Consider using a subquery, like:

```
SELECT col1
,      col1 + field3 AS col3 
FROM   (
       SELECT  field1 + field2 as col1
       ,       field3
       from    core
       ) as SubQueryAlias
```

Answer (score 39):

`select @code:= SUM(field1 + field2), @code+1 from abc;`

But, please be aware of the following (from the [MySQL 5.6 docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html)):

> As a general rule, other than in SET statements, you should never assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same statement. For example, to increment a variable, this is okay:
>
> ```
> SET @a = @a + 1;
> ```
>
> For other statements, such as SELECT, you might get the results you expect, but this is not guaranteed. In the following statement, you might think that MySQL will evaluate @a first and then do an assignment second:
>
> ```
> SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1, ...;
> ```
>
> However, the order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined.

So, use at your own risk.

Comment: That's sweet syntactic sugar. :-)

Comment: Sadly, this works brilliantly in a query, but not in a View :(

Comment: @kenn Worked fine for me, on Mysql!

Comment: @Melvin RTFM http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html "...the order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined." In fact I get NULL with the above query.

Comment: @kenn, I added the caveat as an edit. Thanks for the heads up, this might bite people who are unaware of it.

Comment: This is working great when testing something simple, but when I apply this to a query that I'm using in production, I get unreliable results. The field value will be there and not there sometimes.

Answer (score 16):

You can `select` the alias:

```
SELECT SUM(field1 + field2) AS col1, (select col1) + field3 AS col3 from core
```

This works.

Comment: It works. Same problem and same solution as this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077475/using-an-alias-in-sql-calculations

Comment: this works great in mysql.. not sure about other dbs.  should be top answer

Comment: This does not work ('reference to group function' error) if the column you reference to is calculated based on a group function like in `SELECT MAX(ID) AS c1, (SELECT c1) AS c2 FROM log GROUP BY ID` - it works however if you replace `MAX(ID)` with `ID` in this example.

Comment: @ChristopherK. is correct.  I ran into this as well.  I was defining a view, however, rather than just running a straight query.  As such, I resolved this by nesting one view inside of the other.  The first view uses the aggregate functions.  The second (wrapper view) performs calculations over the top of that first one.  Problem solved.

Answer (score 5):

```
select @code:= SUM(field1 + field2), (@code*1) from abc;
```

@code*1 covert into numeric expression and you can use anywhere like

```
select @code:= SUM(field1 + field2), (@code*1)+field3 from abc;
```

Comment: I came here to vote you up, this works perfectly in our scenario. Replaced @code by a more hungarian/code style friendly variable and kept the AS.
`@fVariable:=SUM(column) AS alias` (alias should be encased by backticks, SO doesn't render them properly.

Comment: @ReSpawN It's undefined behaviour. It happened to give you the answer you expected that time. Since it's open source, certain read + write usages are safe for a particular build (if you don't consider that a contradiction in terms) if you inspect the code.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is no:

```
mysql> select 1 as a, a + 1 as b;
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'a' in 'field list'

postgresql# select 1 as a, a + 1 as b;
ERROR:  column "a" does not exist
```

That said, some SQL implementations allow to use the aliases in where/group by/having clauses, e.g.:

```
postgresql# select 1 as a group by a; -- 1 row
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using it with aggregate function (group by) and if it doesn't work for you place the calculated column to the end with forward column referecing.

```html
SELECT FNC2(AF), FNC1(A) AS AF,  B, C,  FROM Table GROUP BY ...

1st one doesn't work due to forward column referencing. Do this instead 

SELECT FNC1(A) AS AF, B, C, FNC2((SELECT AF)) FROM Table GROUP BY ...
```