# How to store Query Result in variable using mysql

Tags: mysql, database, variables, set

```
SET @v1 := SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_rating;
SELECT @v1
```

When I execute this query with `set` variable this error is shown.

```
Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
near 'SELECT count(*) FROM user_rating' at line 1

Execution Time : 00:00:00:000
Transfer Time  : 00:00:00:000
Total Time     : 00:00:00:000

(1 row(s) returned)
Execution Time : 00:00:00:343
Transfer Time  : 00:00:00:000
Total Time     : 00:00:00:343
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081436/how-to-use-alias-as-field-in-mysql/6081523#6081523

Answer (score 183, accepted):

Surround that select with parentheses.

```
SET @v1 := (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_rating);
SELECT @v1;
```

Comment: Should that sub query just be containing 1 row and 1 column? 1. `#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row `, 2. `#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s) `

Comment: @RajatGupta: where are you running it? And define "not working".

Comment: @Shafizadeh: yep, that subquery should return just one row and column

Comment: Does not work for me, tried on phpmyadmin mysql. An error appears saying "A new instruction was found, but there is no delimiter between it and the previous" (translated from german).

Comment: @Black: perhaps, some of the other answers will work.

Comment: It seems that the return value has to be one, not a list of values

Comment: How to declare @v1 in a stored procedure? What would be the type?

Comment: im having a login query but it wont work ```:SET @res := (
SELECT concat_ws(' ', users.first_name, users.last_name), COUNT(roles.id) AS role_count
FROM user_roles
JOIN users on users.id = user_roles.user_id
JOIN roles on roles.id = user_roles.role_id
GROUP BY users.id
);

SELECT @res;

Comment: how to add if statement  IF @v1  = 10 THEN SELECT "TEN" ELSE SELECT "NOT TEN" END IF

Answer (score 46):

Additionally, if you want to set multiple variables at once by one query, you can use the other syntax for setting variables which goes like this: `SELECT @varname:=value`.

A practical example:

```
SELECT @total_count:=COUNT(*), @total_price:=SUM(quantity*price) FROM items ...
```

Answer (score 12):

use this

```
 SELECT weight INTO @x FROM p_status where tcount='value' LIMIT 1;
```

tested and workes fine...

Answer (score 6):

```
Select count(*) from table_name into @var1; 
Select @var1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use MySQL `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` if you want to save query result as a temp table for reuse in subsequent queries.

See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-temporary-table.html

```
-- begin: drop first just in case
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS myDb.temp_variable; 
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE myDb.temp_variable SELECT * FROM myDb.student ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 25;

-- your scripts
SELECT * FROM myDb.temp_variable;

-- end: drop to prevent cached values accessed by other queries
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS myDb.temp_variable;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to use the variable inside  `SELECT... WHERE... IN (*here*)`.

Use `GROUP_CONCAT` and `find_in_set`.

```
-- initialise with a comma-separated string
SET @emails = 'test1@example.com,test2@example.com,test3@example.com';

-- search condition
SELECT * FROM customer WHERE find_in_set(email, @emails);

-- or, you can initialise the variable using query results
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(phone) INTO @activeCustomerPhones FROM customer WHERE status = 'ACTIVE';

SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE find_in_set(phone, @activeCustomerPhones);

/* 
customer:
- phone
- email
- status 

transaction:
- phone
*/
```