# Save Variable in SQL

Tags: mysql

Is there a way for me to save the values my `SELECT` statement returns in to a variable in SQL?

This is what i want to do, first i want to `SELECT` all the columns i wanna check so in this case `ItemNames` of the items with `ItemCategory` US.

```
SELECT `ItemName` where `ItemCategory´= 'US'
```

Then I want to save the `ItemName` from the statement above into a variable in SQL to use it later on in the same query. Like this:

```
SELECT `DatabaseID` where `Project` NOT LIKE `myVariable`
```

Thanks in regards

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070406/how-to-store-query-result-in-variable-using-mysql

Comment: Why don't just mix them up together?

Answer (score 7):

You can try like this:

```
SELECT `ItemName` into @myVar FROM mytable where `ItemCategory´= 'US';
```

or

```
SELECT @myVar := `ItemName` FROM mytable where `ItemCategory´= 'US'
```

However you can combine your query to one like this:

```
SELECT `DatabaseID` from mytable 
where `Project` NOT IN (SELECT `ItemName` where `ItemCategory´= 'US')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @var varchar(50);
SELECT @var = 'US' 
SELECT * FROM Country where Name NOT LIKE @var
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is store the results in a variable table or temporary table, something like this:

**SQL Server:**

```
create table #Temp
(
    ItemName As Varchar(50)
    --col2 AS Int, 
    --col3 As Varchar(20)
    --...
)
```

**MySQL**

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1 (ItemName VARCHAR(50)) -- You can add more columns: (ItemName VARCHAR(50), col2 int NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, col3 VARCHAR(20),...)
```

Then put the results in the table #Temp or table1

**SQL Server**

```
Insert Into #Temp SELECT ItemName FROM mytable where ItemCategory= 'US';
```

**MySQL**

```
Insert Into table1 SELECT ItemName FROM mytable where ItemCategory= 'US';
```

And then you can play with both tables and make different operations (e.g. make joins)