# Return console commands using python and mysql

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to make a python program which uses python to interact with MySQL. What I want to do is to have the program return and store into a variable the return of that command variable.

For example, if I entered into the MySQL command line `SHOW tables;`, it would show me all the tables, and it would look something like this:

```
+----------------+
| Tables_in_test |
+----------------+
| food           |
| games          |
| movies         |
+----------------+
```

I want to know if there's any way to get that output into, for instance, a variable in python.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Write a stored procedure where it uses the cursor.

```
cursor contains the rows of the command SHOW tables
```

when you call the sp through your code[python]
you can get the results

Comment: What I want is for the program not requiring a previous knowledge of the tables in the database, but that it uses the result of the code and stores it in a variable.

Comment: unable to get what exactly u want to achieve, would u like to elaborate ?

Comment: I was a way to get the output of the console into a variable. For example, if I typed 'show tables;", the result of that would be put into a variable. That result would be the table shown above.

Comment: if i understood it correctly, you want the sql command output to be stored into a variable[pyhton]
As i mentioned earlier,
please look into the following items[select ..into , cursor, storedprocedure ]
if that is not your requirement , then this might help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070406/how-to-store-query-result-in-variable-using-mysql