# How to store results (rows) of a query in a variable when the there is multiple rows

Tags: mysql, variables, subquery

I'm trying to store results of a query into a variable. But I have the following error.

```
subquery returns more than 1 row
```

This is the code that I used:

```
set @var := (select country from (SELECT country FROM employeeTABLE 
order by rand() limit 250)t where country='USA');
```

The Query randomly selects 250 countries and then return country=USA among the 250 randomly selected countries. I want to store these USA in a variable.
Suppose there are 3 country=USA in the 250 randomly selected countries. So I expect to have:

```
USA
USA
USA
```

Comment: Your query doesn't make sense, you could write this as `set @var := 'USA'`

Comment: I need all of them. I mean the count(*) of the query is needed as well.

Comment: Then properly explain in your question what it is you want and what your issue is. Or did you mean `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employeeTABLE 
WHERE country = 'USA'`?

Comment: May be this may help you... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070406/how-to-store-query-result-in-variable-using-mysql