# get count of each users role

Tags: mysql, count

I want to get each user role count, in the user-role table.

I can get the user's name with the role name in a result but I don't know how to get count of roles for each user.

my query:

```sql
SELECT users.first_name,
roles.name FROM user_roles
JOIN users
on users.id = user_roles.user_id
JOIN roles
on roles.id = user_roles.role_id;
```

#Database Structure:

```
roles => [id,name]
users => [id,first_name,last_name]
user_roles => [user_id,role_id]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `GROUP BY` and `COUNT`:

```
SELECT users.first_name, COUNT(roles.id) AS role_count
FROM user_roles
JOIN users on users.id = user_roles.user_id
JOIN roles on roles.id = user_roles.role_id
GROUP BY users.id
```

Comment: do you know how to make contact to columns in one column ... like (users.first_name, users.last_name) AS full name?

Comment: `concat_ws(' ', users.first_name, users.last_name)`.

Comment: im trying to store this result like this link :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070406/how-to-store-query-result-in-variable-using-mysql/23282102 .. but it wont work 