# Set the result of a query to a variable in MySQL

Tags: mysql, variables

This should be a simple syntax thing:
I'm trying to set a variable in MySQL equal to the result of a query for instance:

```
SET @variable1 = SELECT salary FROM employee_info WHERE emp_id = 12345678;
```

Basically I want the salary from that employee to be stored as a variable that I can then manipulate and add.

What would the correct syntax for this be because I can't get it to work.

Comment: [Duplicate][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081436/how-to-use-alias-as-field-in-mysql/6081523#6081523

Answer (score 73, accepted):

```
SELECT salary INTO @variable1 FROM employee_info WHERE emp_id = 12345678 LIMIT 1;
```

or

```
SET @variable1 = (SELECT salary FROM employee_info WHERE emp_id = 12345678 LIMIT 1);

SELECT @variable1;
```

Comment: For some reason this is returning a null, any idea why?

Comment: what is the result you get when you run `SELECT salary FROM employee_info WHERE emp_id = 12345678`?

Comment: I was also getting null, my error was that I had used the same variable name as my field name, so `SET salary = (SELECT salary FROM.....`

Comment: @Damith, There is [actually 4 different syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15581005/set-a-variable-in-select-statement-mysql/29391880#29391880) to accomplish this thing.

Comment: The solutions are not exactly interchangeable: SELECT INTO variable1 will not change variable1 if the result of the query is an empty set, while SET variable1 = etc. will asign NULL to variable1 in that case. I think that this difference should be pointed out, because it can be meaningful in a lot of use cases.

Comment: unable to get the result in variable..mysql showing error wrong syntax near `SELECT`

Answer (score 13):

You can even fill multiple variables in a single query.

```
SELECT salary, salary_group INTO @var1, @var2 FROM employee_info WHERE emp_id = 12345678;
```

Answer (score 4):

You are quite close to the right syntax. Here it is:

```
SET @variable1 = (SELECT salary FROM employee_info WHERE emp_id = 12345678);
```

and then print the variable like this:

```
SELECT @variable1;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT @code:=salary FROM employee_info WHERE emp_id = 12345678;
```

To check salary,

```
SELECT @code;
```

The result of salary will be initialized in `code`.

[More Information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081436/how-to-use-alias-as-field-in-mysql/6081523#6081523)

Comment: Please provide Some explantion to your query so that OP and other user may understand better

Comment: @sundarnataraj User-Defined Variables. You can find explanation @ http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html

Answer (score 2):

**Set the result of a query to a variable in MySQL**

```
Select  @Amount1:=  Amount FROM table where id=57703;
```

Comment: I used eveything here but it is not working for [my code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49196568/mysql-random-data-create-from-tables)

Answer (score 1):

```
select @variable1 := salary FROM employee_info WHERE emp_id = 12345678;
```

Comment: This doesn't work dude. You need to [add a colon](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29391880/632951) for it to work.

Comment: change '=' to ':='

Comment: Although this code may be help to solve the problem,
providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
SELECT weight INTO @x FROM p_status where tcount=['value'] LIMIT 1;
```

tested and workes fine...