# SET a variable in SELECT statement - MySQL

Tags: mysql, variables, concatenation, variable-assignment

I'm using this code which has an error:

```
SET @rejects = '';

SELECT *
FROM list
WHERE maker = 1
    AND by_ids IN ('10','11')
    AND country LIKE '%I%'
    AND (
        src IS NULL
        || src NOT IN (@rejects)
        AND checkSrc(src) = 'yes'
        AND SET @rejects = CONCAT(@rejects,',',src)
    );
```

What's causing the issue?

Comment: Could be `by_ids INT('10','11')`  to  `by_ids IN('10','11') `?

Comment: Why `AND SET @rejects = CONCAT(@rejects,',',src)` in `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Thats what i want, i want to concat the value of each searched src into @rejects variable.

Comment: || should not be used as an or.

Comment: You can see examples when searching for "MySQL group by greatest/top n" or similar - this is because MySQL solutions require some interesting hacks (usually just incrementing a counter).

Answer (score 17):

The issue is that you cannot mix `select` and `set` in one statement, there'll surely be syntax error:

```
select*from t where 1 and set@a=1;
```

> <sup>ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'set@a=1' at line 1</sup>

If you want to do `set` within `select`, use [the colon equals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/assignment-operators.html#operator_assign-value) syntax. Change this:

```
select*from t where 1 and set@a=1;
```

into:

```
select*,@a:=1 from t where 1;
```

Here's how you update the variable **upon each** row:

```
create table t(id int); insert t values(1),(2),(3);
set@a=0;
select@a:=id from t;
```

> ```
> +--------+
> | @a:=id |
> +--------+
> |      1 |
> |      2 |
> |      3 |
> +--------+
> ```

And you can even do `concat`:

```
set@a='0';
select @a:=concat(@a,',',id)from t;
```

> ```
> +-----------------------+
> | @a:=concat(@a,',',id) |
> +-----------------------+
> | 0,1                   |
> | 0,1,2                 |
> | 0,1,2,3               |
> +-----------------------+
> ```

Or `concat` without the leading `0`:

```
set@a='';
select @a:=concat(@a,if(@a='','',','),id)from t;
```

> ```
> +------------------------------------+
> | @a:=concat(@a,if(@a='','',','),id) |
> +------------------------------------+
> | 1                                  |
> | 1,2                                |
> | 1,2,3                              |
> +------------------------------------+
> ```

However, the manual **explicitly** states that this is dangerous: [image: link]

> ...you should **never** assign a value to a user variable and read the
>   value within the same statement...
>
> ...you might get the results you expect, but this is **not
>   guaranteed**.
>
> ...the order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is
>   **undefined**.

This has also been mentioned [on Xaprb](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/02/how-to-number-rows-in-mysql/#playing-with-fire).

Lastly, if you're doing *quirky* things like assigning differing value types to the variable and etc, [checkout the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html) to be sure you understand the intricate mechanisms.

Comment: _"...you should never assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same statement..."_ that saved me a lot of trial-and-error.

Answer (score 2):

Then you might write your query like this.

```
SET @rejects = '';
SELECT @rejects = CONCAT(@rejects,',',src) FROM list WHERE maker = 1 AND by_ids IN ('10','11') AND country LIKE '%I%' AND 
(src IS NULL OR src NOT IN (@rejects) AND checkSrc(src) = 'yes');
SELECT @rejects;
```

Comment: What is your expected output? Also if src is null then there could be a problem. Can you post your table structure and expected output?