# how could i solve this code problem in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, while-loop

i want to rank my users by score from my 'scores' table with php using mysql . i wrote this query that is actually working in SQL Tab of phpMyAdmin :

```
SET @rank=0;
SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank, name, score
  FROM scores
 ORDER BY score DESC;
```

but i cant figure it out , how to use it in my php Code . i tried:

```
 $result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo  $row["score"]. $E ."     ". $row["name"]. $N  ;
        echo  PHP_EOL;
        echo  PHP_EOL;
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

i think my problem is with my while loop . but i dont know what should i do :(

PleaseHelp();                :(

---

guys problem was solved . Our Dear Friend @mallik1055 noticed that the problem was with query and im sending multiple request . then i noticed That phpMyAdmin automatically runs multiple query unlike PHP , so i tried mysqli_multi_query and it worked , thank you a lot <3

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I believe you don't need this part `SET @rank=0;`, because of the `;` this is two SQL statments, which typically you can't do in a single query.  It's a security feature to prevent some forms of SQLInjection.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15581005/set-a-variable-in-select-statement-mysql

Comment: Linked in one of the answers is to use [Colon equals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/assignment-operators.html#operator_assign-value)  `:=` Which you are already doing.  Typically I don't use variables like this, I remember doing it one time a couple years ago.... lol

Comment: thanks @ArtisticPhoenix , i test my own query in mysql and it worked , and my php code would work too if i Delete my while loop . but it only give me one row in return . im sure my problem is in while part of The code , no the query part :( i tried your tips too , but nothing changed :(

Comment: @gabriel I am surprised your $conn->query($sql) works without error considering it is a multi-query. Anyways, try splitting the queries and running back to back or use mysqli:multi_query. I don't see a problem with while loop.

Comment: @mallik1055 thanks man , i noticed That phpMyAdmin automatically runs multiple query unlike PHP , so i tried mysqli_multi_query and it worked , thank you a lot <3

Answer (score 0):

That should work.

```
$rank = 0;
$rank = $rank+1;

$sql = "SELECT rank, name, score FROM scores ORDER BY score DESC";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

if ($row > 0) {
    while($row > 0) {
        echo  $row["score"].$E."     ".$row["name"].$N.;
        echo  PHP_EOL;
        echo  PHP_EOL;
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: `rank` isn't a column in the `scores` table. This won't work.

Comment: @Arzach yeas danblack is correct . Rank is not a column in my code , it would be created after the query

Answer (score 0):

`$row["rank"]` is an element in your fetched rows, just like `"score"` and `"name"`