# how to save select result into variable in mysql

Tags: mysql

origin link: https://leetcode.com/problems/human-traffic-of-stadium/description/
the ideal pseudo code I want is

```
select id from Stadium where people >= 100 into @tmp;
select * from Stadium 
where id in tmp and (
(id + 1 in tmp and id + 2 in tmp) or
(id + 1 in tmp and id - 1 in tmp) or
(id - 1 in tmp and id - 2 in tmp) 
)
order by visit_date;
```

what I tried is as follow, but that is too stubborn:

```
select * from Stadium 
where id in (select id from Stadium where people >= 100) and (
(id + 1 in (select id from Stadium where people >= 100) and id + 2 in (select id from Stadium where people >= 100)) or
(id + 1 in (select id from Stadium where people >= 100) and id - 1 in (select id from Stadium where people >= 100)) or
(id - 1 in (select id from Stadium where people >= 100) and id - 2 in (select id from Stadium where people >= 100)) 
)
order by visit_date;
```

Comment: If Leetcode supported MySQL 8.0, I would suggest using a common table expression, but I recall they are still using MySQL 5

Comment: The proposed dup target is about Oracle SQL, which ignores many MySQL based Questions, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10741612/set-the-result-of-a-query-to-a-variable-in-mysql) about using SET with a select statement.  However the wording of the Question here is confusing to me, as it seems less about assigning a value to a variable than about creating a temp table.  Voting to close for lack of clarity rather than as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to return a list of results into a variable? Cause honestly, that gets complicated and, honestly, isn't worth the headache. Right now the way you wrote it, it is returning table data which cannot be added into a variable. If you want the ids in a list, you could do:

```
`SET @tmp = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id Separator ',') where people >= 100);`
```

This will give you a comma separated list, like 'Stadium1,Stadium2,...' which you could use for other mysql functions like FIND_IN_SET(), etc. [(more examples here)](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_mysql.asp)

I suggest making CTE(s) with the stadiums that meet your criteria, then JOIN to the original table and query away. Such as:

```
WITH cte (id, name, columns...) 
AS (Select * from Stadium where people >= 100)
/* Select statements */
```

CTEs make querying much much faster and don't require creating and dropping tables. you can also create multiple CTEs by just putting a comma after each one. Hope this helps!