# Use a select result and compare it

Tags: mysql, select

My question:

How do I get MySQL to use in a select a previouly selected value without repeating itself

My Answer, taken from [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6081523/1709763)

Set a variable direclty on the SELECT like this:

```
SELECT @q:= ##longQuery## AS a, (@q>2) AS b;
```

I had this MySQL:

```
SELECT ##longQuery## AS a, (a>2) AS b;
```

but I got:

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'a' in 'field list'
```

I didn't want to repeat the **##longQuery##**, because it is actually quite lengthy on the real code.

Thank you

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Please format code by indenting with four spaces. It makes it much easier to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible solutions:

1. Use a subquery
2. Use a variable

**The subquery solution**

```
select a, a>2 as b
from (select 1 as a) as q;
```

**The 'variable'  solution**

```
set @a = 1;
select @a as a, @a>2 as b;
```

Comment: You are repeating "a". I need to, either to not repeat "a" (or in my example, "1"), or find a way that MySQL understands "a" as a value previously selected.

Comment: @Florius then go with the subquery solution... You cannot reference in a `select` a column name defined as an alias in the same `select`. Anyway, both approaches work... the second approach is split in a two-step process, but it works

Comment: @Florius if `a` is the result of a subquery (as your edit suggests), then you can also store the result of that subquery in a variable: `set @a = (select ...)`. Of course, this 'select' *must* return a single column and a single row

Comment: I found a way to define a variable inside the SELECT, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using a subQuery will work

```
SELECT a, (a>2) AS b
FROM (
  SELECT 1 AS a
) f
```