# Doing arithmetic on alias in SQL

Tags: sql, alias, h2

In my SQL query I need to do some arithmetic on alias.

```
SELECT 
    MY_COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_USING_SUM_AND_CASEWHEN AS MYALIASNAME1, 
    MY_SECOND_COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_USING_SUM_AND_CASEWHEN AS MYALIASNAME2,  
    MYALIASNAME1 - MYALIASNAME2 AS MYALIASHNAME3
FROM 
    MYTABLE
```

However, this does not work because it is not treating `MYALIASNAME1` and `MYALIASNAME2` as columns. Any ideas how can I achieve this?

I am using H2, specifically h2-1.3.173.jar. I am using it in server mode.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081436/how-to-use-alias-as-field-in-mysql
 pls have look is it making any sense to u.

Comment: Please tell us what **concrete database system** this is for - many things are vendor-specific. Are you using MySQL? Postgres? SQL Server? Oracle? IBM DB2? Something else entirely? Please update your tags to show what database system (and which version of it!) you're using - thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this.

```
SELECT X.MYALIASNAME1 - X.MYALIASNAME2 AS MYALIASNAME3 FROM
(
    SELECT 
        MY_COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_USING_SUM_AND_CASEWHEN AS MYALIASNAME1, 
        MY_SECOND_COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_USING_SUM_AND_CASEWHEN AS MYALIASNAME2

    FROM 
        MYTABLE
)X
```

Answer (score 1):

Use *Common Table Expressions*:

```
with cte as (
    select MY_COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_USING_SUM_AND_CASEWHEN AS MYALIASNAME1, 
        MY_SECOND_COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_USING_SUM_AND_CASEWHEN AS MYALIASNAME2
        
    from table
)
    
select MYALIASNAME1 - MYALIASNAME2 AS MYALIASHNAME3 from cte
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the alias

```
SELECT 
   MY_COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_USING_SUM_AND_CASEWHEN AS MYALIASNAME1, 
   MY_SECOND_COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_USING_SUM_AND_CASEWHEN AS MYALIASNAME2,  
   MY_COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_USING_SUM_AND_CASEWHEN  - MY_SECOND_COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_USING_SUM_AND_CASEWHEN AS MYALIASHNAME3
FROM 
    MYTABLE
```

Or use an intermediate step

```
SELECT MYALIASNAME1, MYALIASNAME2,  MYALIASNAME1 - MYALIASNAME2 AS MYALIASHNAME3
FROM  (

   SELECT 
       MY_COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_USING_SUM_AND_CASEWHEN AS MYALIASNAME1, 
       MY_SECOND_COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_USING_SUM_AND_CASEWHEN AS MYALIASNAME2
   FROM 
       MYTABLE
 ) TableAlias
```

Answer (score 0):

it will work...

```
"SELECT 
    MY_COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_USING_SUM_AND_CASEWHEN AS MYALIASNAME1, 
    MY_SECOND_COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_USING_SUM_AND_CASEWHEN AS MYALIASNAME2,  
    (MY_COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_USING_SUM_AND_CASEWHEN) - (MY_SECOND_COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_USING_SUM_AND_CASEWHEN) AS MYALIASHNAME3
FROM 
    MYTABLE"
```