# dummy column value to another dummy column in Hive

Tags: hadoop

I want to select value of a dummy column into another dummy column

### something like below

```
select a+b+c as mynum, b/mynum as newnum 

from mytable
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081436/how-to-use-alias-as-field-in-mysql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use alias as field in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081436/how-to-use-alias-as-field-in-mysql)