# How do I use alias in where clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, qtsql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Referring to a Column Alias in a WHERE Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370114/referring-to-a-column-alias-in-a-where-clause)

```
   SELECT
Trade.TradeId, 
Isnull(Securities.SecurityType,'Other') SecurityType, 
TableName,
CASE 
WHEN 
SecurityTrade.SecurityId IS NOT NULL  
THEN 
SecurityTrade.SecurityId
ELSE 
Trade.SecurityId
END AS PricingSecurityID,
sum(Trade.Quantity)OVER(Partition by Securities.SecurityType, SecurityTrade.SecurityId,Trade.Price, Buy,Long ) as sumQuantity,
--added porfolio id for Getsumofqantity
Trade.PortfolioId,

Trade.Price,
case
when (Buy = 1 and Long = 1) then 1
when (Buy = 0 and Long = 0) then 1
else 0
end Position
from
Fireball_Reporting..Trade

where porfolioid =5 and Position =1
```

i want to use  Position =1   in my where clause which is an alias of case

```
case
when (Buy = 1 and Long = 1) then 1
when (Buy = 0 and Long = 0) then 1
else 0
end Position
```

How can I use it in where clause?

I tried zo directly use that CASE statement in where clause, but failed.

```
WHERE Trade.SecurityId = @SecurityId AND PortfolioId = @GHPortfolioID AND
                (case when (Buy = 1 and Long = 1) then 1 when (Buy = 0 and Long = 0) then 1 else 0 end Position = 1)
```

Comment: You cannot unless you add another select and check postion = 1 on outer query.

Comment: What SQL language are you using?

Comment: T SQL in sql server 2008

Answer (score 84, accepted):

The [SQL-Server docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173451.aspx) says:

> column_alias can be used in an ORDER BY clause, but it **cannot be used in a WHERE, GROUP BY, or HAVING clause**.

Similar in the [MySQL doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/problems-with-alias.html) it says:

> Standard SQL **disallows references to column aliases in a WHERE clause**. This restriction is imposed because when the WHERE clause is evaluated, the column value may not yet have been determined.

In **MySQL** you can at least [reuse aliases in the **SELECT** clause](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18020948/575376)

Answer (score 56):

You can't, not directly.

If you wrap the whole query in a sub-query, however, it works fine.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
(
  SELECT
    Trade.TradeId, 
    Isnull(Securities.SecurityType,'Other') SecurityType, 
    TableName,
    CASE 
      WHEN SecurityTrade.SecurityId IS NOT NULL THEN SecurityTrade.SecurityId
                                                ELSE Trade.SecurityId
    END AS PricingSecurityID,
    sum(Trade.Quantity)OVER(Partition by Securities.SecurityType,
    SecurityTrade.SecurityId,Trade.Price, Buy,Long ) as sumQuantity,
    --added porfolio id for Getsumofqantity
    Trade.PortfolioId,
    Trade.Price,
    case
      when (Buy = 1 and Long = 1) then 1
      when (Buy = 0 and Long = 0) then 1
                                  else 0
    end Position
  from
    Fireball_Reporting..Trade
  where
    porfolioid = 5
)
  AS data
WHERE
  Position = 1
```

This means that you don't need to repeat the `CASE` statement in `WHERE` clause.  (Maintainable and DRY).

It is also a structure that allows the optimiser to behave *as if* you *had* simply repeated yourself in the `WHERE` clause.

It's also very portable to other RDBMSs.

In SQL Server, then you also have another option...

```
SELECT
  Trade.TradeId, 
  Isnull(Securities.SecurityType,'Other') SecurityType, 
  TableName,
  CASE 
    WHEN SecurityTrade.SecurityId IS NOT NULL THEN SecurityTrade.SecurityId
                                              ELSE Trade.SecurityId
  END AS PricingSecurityID,
  sum(Trade.Quantity)OVER(Partition by Securities.SecurityType,
  SecurityTrade.SecurityId,Trade.Price, Buy,Long ) as sumQuantity,
  --added porfolio id for Getsumofqantity
  Trade.PortfolioId,
  Trade.Price,
  position.val AS Position
from
  Fireball_Reporting..Trade
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT
    case
      when (Buy = 1 and Long = 1) then 1
      when (Buy = 0 and Long = 0) then 1
                                  else 0
    end AS val
)
  AS position
where
  porfolioid = 5
  AND position.val = 1
```

Comment: Juergen's answer and your answer relates to the fact that "..when WHERE clause is evaluated, the column value may not yet have been determined." but since you're using sub query that will have been.

Comment: sub-query is a brilliant solution!

Answer (score 9):

You can't directly do this...but you can wrap an additional select around it all and use the where clause:

```
    select * from 
   (   SELECT
   Trade.TradeId, 
   Isnull(Securities.SecurityType,'Other') SecurityType, 
   TableName,
   CASE 
   WHEN 
   SecurityTrade.SecurityId IS NOT NULL  
   THEN 
   SecurityTrade.SecurityId
   ELSE 
   Trade.SecurityId
   END AS PricingSecurityID,
   sum(Trade.Quantity)OVER(Partition by Securities.SecurityType,       SecurityTrade.SecurityId,Trade.Price, Buy,Long ) as sumQuantity,
    --added porfolio id for Getsumofqantity
    Trade.PortfolioId,
     Trade.Price,
     case
     when (Buy = 1 and Long = 1) then 1
     when (Buy = 0 and Long = 0) then 1
     else 0
    end Position
    from
    Fireball_Reporting..Trade
    where porfolioid =5 and Position =1 
    )x
    where x.position = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably missing something but surely this will cover it:

`WHERE (Buy = 1 and Long = 1) OR (Buy = 0 and Long = 0)`

Comment: It does.  But "Don't Repeat Yourself" (DRY) is a basic principle that aids maintenance and debugging *enormously*.  So, being able to reference one calculation many times is highly desirable.