# Use an alias into Sql request

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to use an alias in the following sql request.

I can't find a workable way to do this.

Where is my error please ?

Thanks.

```
SELECT * , get_distance_metres('44.12306832854452',  '-77.34566731195382', Latitude, Longitude)
AS proximite_r
FROM myDB
WHERE  `Status` =  '1'
AND  `proximite_r` <  '1000'
ORDER BY proximite_r ASC
```

This line

```
AND  `proximite_r` <  '1000'
```

Returns the following error

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'proximite_r' in 'where clause'
```

Comment: instead of `where` use `having`

Comment: `AND get_distance_metres('44.12306832854452',  '-77.34566731195382', Latitude, Longitude) <1000`

Comment: Based on the prolific use of backticks, I assume the database in MySQL and am tagging it as such.

Comment: Also, there's loads of other questions exactly the same. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/356675/3210837 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/13031013/3210837 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/200200/3210837 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/8370114/3210837.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WHERE` expression is processed **before** the `SELECT` expression; therefore, you can not use an alias in the `WHERE` expression.

However, with MySQL, you could use `HAVING` (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html):

```
SELECT * , get_distance_metres('44.12306832854452',  '-77.34566731195382', Latitude, Longitude)
AS proximite_r
FROM myDB
WHERE  `Status` =  '1'
HAVING `proximite_r` <  '1000'
ORDER BY proximite_r ASC
```

Also, `proiximate_r` should be an `int` or `bigint` and you should use `< 1000`, instead of `< '1000'`.

Comment: As a note, this only works in MySQL.  And, it is not exactly a limitation of SQL.  It is a feature actually, based on the fact that the `where` clause is logically processed before the `select`.  This ordering is important for avoiding issues of column/alias ambiguity.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I forgot that, but you're right. I've edited the answer.