# Using a derived-column as key for a JOIN

Tags: sql

Given

```
CREATE TABLE Person (
  id bigint,
  first_name nvarchar(60),
  last_name nvarchar(60),
  custom_employee_id nvarchar(60)
);

CREATE TABLE User (
  id bigint,
  username nvarchar(60),
  department nvarchar(60)
);

INSERT INTO Person ( id,first_name,last_name,custom_employee_id)
VALUES (1,'steve','rogers','00009094');

INSERT INTO User ( id,username,department)
VALUES( 23,'9094','accounting');
```

I want to join on Person.custom_employee_id and User.username. Both are nvarchars so this should be cake but custom_employee_id has embedded leading zeros and also nulls to contend with.

```
SELECT A.id, A.first_name, A.last_name, A.custom_employee_id
     , CAST( CAST( A.custom_employee_id) AS bigint) AS nvarchar) AS trythis
FROM Person A
WHERE ISDECIMAL( A.custom_employee_id) =1
```

seems to get me close with

```
1,'steve','rogers','00009094','9094'
```

so trying

```
SELECT A.id, A.first_name, A.last_name, A.custom_employee_id
     , CAST( CAST( A.custom_employee_id) AS bigint) AS nvarchar) AS trythis
     , B.department
FROM Person A
LEFT JOIN USER B ON B.username = 'trythis'
WHERE ISDECIMAL( A.custom_employee_id) =1
```

does execute but yields

```
1,'steve','rogers','00009094','9094',NULL
```

instead of the hoped-for

```
1,'steve','rogers','00009094','9094','accounting'
```

So how must I adjust my query?

TIA,

Still-learning Steve

Comment: Please update your tag with the engine you're using (I.e. MySQL, SQL Server, etc.) Also, is custom_employee_id always padded with zeros or can it be an extra value I.e. 20009094

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use alias in where clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031013/how-do-i-use-alias-in-where-clause)

Comment: Why not use INTEGER as datatype for the column `custom_employee_id`? that seems more appropriate.  You can leave the formatting (adding of leading zeros) to you output tool.

Answer (score 0):

So two possible answers here but keep in mind neither are optimal as you never want to do operations in your match as this is not [SARGable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable#:%7E:text=In%20relational%20databases%2C%20a%20condition,contraction%20of%20Search%20ARGument%20ABLE.). So long as the tables remain relatively small this shouldn't a noticeable performance impact.

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM @Person P 
JOIN @User U 
    ON CONVERT(int ,U.[username]) = CONVERT(int ,P.[custom_employee_id]) 
    
SELECT 
    * 
FROM @Person P 
JOIN @User U 
    ON RIGHT('00000000' + U.[username], 8) = P.[custom_employee_id]
```

On the second query "RIGHT('00000000' + U.[username], 8)" is assuming that "P.[custom_employee_id]" is always a length of 8 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out just replicating the double-cast and switching from LEFT JOIN to JOIN did the trick

```
SELECT A.id, A.first_name, A.last_name, A.custom_employee_id
     , CAST( CAST( A.custom_employee_id) AS bigint) AS nvarchar) AS trythis
     , B.department
FROM Person A
JOIN USER B ON B.username = CAST( CAST( A.custom_employee_id) AS bigint) AS nvarchar)
WHERE ISDECIMAL( A.custom_employee_id) = 1
```

Thanks to all that replied!

CASE CLOSED

Still-learning Steve