# Adding up Alias with other MySQL column value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one problem with this query; I can't seem to get `((total + rec_host) / 2) AS total2` to work. How would I go about this procedure without doing:

`((((rank_ur + rank_scs + rank_tsk + rank_csb + rank_vfm + rank_orr) / 6) + rec_host ) / 2)`

Here's my Query:

```
   SELECT host_name, 
       SUM(rank_ur) AS cnt1, 
       SUM(rank_scs) AS cnt2,
       SUM(rank_tsk) AS cnt3,
       SUM(rank_csb) AS cnt4,
       SUM(rank_vfm) AS cnt5,
       SUM(rank_orr) AS cnt6,
       SUM(IF(rec_host = 1,1,0)) AS rh1,
       SUM(IF(rec_host = 0,1,0)) AS rh2,
       ((rank_ur + rank_scs + rank_tsk + rank_csb + rank_vfm + rank_orr) / 6) AS total,
       ((total + rec_host) / 2) AS total2
   FROM lhr_reviews 
   GROUP BY host_name
   ORDER BY total 
   DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you could do is this:

```
select x.*, ((x.total + rec_host) / 2) AS total2
from (

SELECT host_name, rec_host,
       SUM(rank_ur) AS cnt1, 
       SUM(rank_scs) AS cnt2,
       SUM(rank_tsk) AS cnt3,
       SUM(rank_csb) AS cnt4,
       SUM(rank_vfm) AS cnt5,
       SUM(rank_orr) AS cnt6,
       SUM(IF(rec_host = 1,1,0)) AS rh1,
       SUM(IF(rec_host = 0,1,0)) AS rh2,
       ((rank_ur + rank_scs + rank_tsk + rank_csb + rank_vfm + rank_orr) / 6) AS total
   FROM lhr_reviews 
   GROUP BY host_name
   ORDER BY total 
   DESC LIMIT 0,10
) as x
;
```

You cannot use the column as an alias when the alias and other column are in the same level of `SELECT`. So you can use a derived query which lets you basically rename your columns and/or name any computed columns.[Check on Rubens Farias and Rob Van Dam answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077475/using-an-alias-in-sql-calculations/2077483#2077483)

PS: will search for a better article to update the answer :)

Comment: Thank you, I learned a lot :) Sorry I couldn't give you the "checkmark" -- He beat you to it :)

Comment: @MahmoudGamal healthy competition is very useful and we get better solutions with it :)

Answer (score 5):

Use a subquery like so:

```
SELECT 
  host_name, 
  cnt1, 
  cnt2,
  cnt3,
  cnt4,
  cnt5,
  cnt6,
  rh1,
  rh2,
  total,
  ((total + rec_host) / 2) AS total2
FROM
(
   SELECT host_name, 
       rec_host,
       SUM(rank_ur) AS cnt1, 
       SUM(rank_scs) AS cnt2,
       SUM(rank_tsk) AS cnt3,
       SUM(rank_csb) AS cnt4,
       SUM(rank_vfm) AS cnt5,
       SUM(rank_orr) AS cnt6,
       SUM(IF(rec_host = 1,1,0)) AS rh1,
       SUM(IF(rec_host = 0,1,0)) AS rh2,
       ((rank_ur + rank_scs + rank_tsk + 
         rank_csb + rank_vfm + rank_orr
         ) / 6) AS total
   FROM lhr_reviews 
   GROUP BY host_name, rec_host
) t 
ORDER BY total 
DESC LIMIT 0,10;
```

Comment: +1 for the speed, I was thinking the same thing....:-)
But in the subquery, please remove the `((total + rec_host) / 2) AS total2`

Comment: I'm confused. You're selecting Aliases? That seems weird to me. although I'm a newbie at MySQL.

Comment: @Justin - Yes these aliases are coming from the inner subquery, and it is OK. Try it.

Comment: MahmoudGamal I guess you missed out `rec_host` in your subquery and what @Sashi Kant mentioned ;)

Comment: @Justin - You are welcome any time, and Sorry for confusion .