# How to use aliases in math operators in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, alias

First of all, please correct me if "alias" is the wrong word. I am talkin about renaming the column with `AS` operator.

So I'm trying calculate an average like this :

```
SELECT
users.username AS player_name,
COUNT(*) AS total_games,
SUM(games.points) AS total_points,
(total_points / total_games) AS average_points

FROM games,
INNER JOIN users
ON games.player_id = users.id
GROUP BY games.player_id
```

*(the query might be wrong, its just a quick example)*

in this query, the line

```
(total_points / total_games) AS average_points
```

gives an error : `unknown column total_points`

so how can I fix this to keep using the aliases, instead of writing this :

```
(SUM(games.points) / COUNT(*) ) AS average_points
```

Thanks for any help !

Comment: Column alias available only after the `SELECT` is processed. So Only the `ORDER BY` has access. In your case, you may need to subquery your `COUNT()` values with an alias, and later refer in the outer part.

Comment: similar question answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18020948/382515)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm fairly sure it's not possible to use aliases like that.  You will have to do it the 'long' way...

```
(SUM(games.points) / COUNT(*) ) AS average_points
```

**Edit:** I wanted to edit this answer to second **@jbeldock** 's answer as a solution I have since used many times myself.  I found myself writing out formulas and re-using them in other parts of queries, leading to big messy queries with copy/pasted sections.   Putting your forumlas in a subquery allows you to use their results in the outer query and make things more elegant.

Comment: Will there be any difference in performance between the approaches suggested above and by @jbeldock?

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately, you cannot use column aliases this way.  They are only available *after* the `SELECT` statement is processed.  However, you can do it in a subquery or a common table expression (CTE).  Here is the simple subquery:

```
SELECT player_name,
       total_games,
       total_points,
       (total_points / total_games) AS average_points
FROM
 (SELECT
 users.username AS player_name,
 COUNT(*) AS total_games,
 SUM(games.points) AS total_points,

 FROM games,
 INNER JOIN users
 ON games.player_id = users.id
 GROUP BY games.player_id) as InnerQuery
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use aliases at the same level they are defined -- you need to put the alias definition in a subquery.  But, you don't need aliases, because SQL has the `AVG()` function:

```
SELECT users.username AS player_name,
       COUNT(*) AS total_games,
       SUM(games.points) AS total_points,
       AVG(games.points) AS average_points
FROM games INNER JOIN
     users
     ON games.player_id = users.id
GROUP BY games.player_id;
```