# Yii2 math in \yii\db\Query()

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

I want to do some math (divide, minus, plus...), and two or more fields' values are using a Yii database query like below. Can I do it like this?

```
 $data = (new \yii\db\Query())
 ->select([
  'date',
  'SUM( IF(status = "Passed", 1, 0) ) AS passed',
  'SUM( IF(status = "Failed", 1, 0) ) AS failed',
  'SUM( IF(status = "On Hold", 1, 0) ) AS onhold',
  'passed/onhold as selfsubmit',
  'COUNT(*) AS total'
 ])
 ->from('qa3d')
 ->groupBy('date')
 ->all();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you cannot do arithmetics (math) with aliases in the same query with MySQL. That [is mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21367981/how-to-use-aliases-in-math-operators-in-sql) as well.

But you can calculate using the `yii\db\Expression` class, because with that, the framework won't try to escape the expression as MySQL columns.

So basically you have to select the expression without the aliases and with the `Expression` class.

For example:

```php
$data = (new \yii\db\Query())
    ->select([
        'date',
        'SUM( IF(status = "Passed", 1, 0) ) AS passed',
        'SUM( IF(status = "Failed", 1, 0) ) AS failed',
        'SUM( IF(status = "On Hold", 1, 0) ) AS onhold',
        new \yii\db\Expression('SUM( IF(status = "Passed", 1, 0) ) / SUM( IF(status = "On Hold", 1, 0) ) AS selfsubmit'),
        'COUNT(*) AS total'
    ])
    ->from('qa3d')
    ->groupBy('date')
    ->all();
```