# Nested conditional statements on Mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm developing a query on phpmyadmin mysql in which I intend to display the running balance of a column say 'CurrentBalance'

The running balance of this column depends when the Activity is a deposit (+), a withdraw (-) , bet (-), payout (+)

What I come up is this

```
SELECT CONCAT("Trans ID ",`TransactionID`) AS ID, 
`DateTime`,`Type` AS Activity, `Amount`, 0 AS Payout, 
CASE WHEN (SELECT Activity) = "deposit" THEN `Amount`+ `playerdb`.`CurrentBalance`
ELSE CASE WHEN (SELECT Activity) = "withdraw" OR (SELECT Activity) = "bet"
THEN CASE WHEN (SELECT Payout) >0 THEN (SELECT Payout) + `playerdb`.`CurrentBalance`
ELSE `Amount` - `playerdb`.`CurrentBalance` END END END AS CurrentBalance 
FROM `transactiondb` LEFT JOIN `playerdb` ON 
`transactiondb`.`PlayerID` = `playerdb`.`PlayerID` 
WHERE `transactiondb`.`PlayerID`=10078 UNION ALL 
SELECT CONCAT("Bet ID ",`BetID`),`DateTime`,"Bet", `BetAmount`,`Payout`, (SELECT CurrentBalance) FROM `betdb` WHERE `PlayerID`=10078 ORDER BY `DateTime`
```

The Idea
http://postimg.org/image/x3fsxq2qz/

Doing the (SELECT CurrentBalance) on the 2nd SELECT statement yields this error

1054 - Unknown column 'CurrentBalance' in 'field list'

I need to get the CurrentBalance of the previous record so I tried using the alias

Is that possible?

Comment: It would be best, if you could provide sample data and the desired result.

Comment: Hi, Please take a look the screenshot here at this link http://postimg.org/image/x3fsxq2qz/

Comment: CASE WHEN (SELECT Activity) <= THIS BIT LOOKS WEIRD!!!

Comment: That seemed the way to reuse Alias I learned it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077475/using-an-alias-in-sql-calculations

Answer (score 1):

This is a "teach a man to fish..." answer, since your question is not yet totally clear to me.

In general you can access the previous row with variables.

Have a look at this example:

```
SELECT
t.*
, @running_total := IF(@foo != foo, 0, @running_total + bar)
, @foo := foo
FROM a_table t
, (SELECT @running_total := 0, @foo := NULL) variable_initialization_subquery
ORDER BY foo;
```

As the subquery alias suggests, here

```
, (SELECT @running_total := 0, @foo := NULL) variable_initialization_subquery
```

we initialize the variables.

We `ORDER BY foo` because there's **no** reliable order in data in a database when you don't specify it clearly.

Then the `SELECT` clause is considered with one column after another. Here the order of the columns is important, too.

First we do this:

```
, @running_total := IF(@foo != foo, 0, @running_total + bar)
```

This calculates a running total for every `foo`. When the `foo` changes, the running total is reset to 0. The `IF()` function works like `IF(<boolean condition>, <then>, <else>)`.
Here the variable `@foo` still has the value of the previous row. The value of the current row is assigned in this line:

```
, @foo := foo
```

I hope you get the idea, feel free to ask if anything is unclear. Oh, and you don't need those `select`s in the `case...when...` parts.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing... giving the man a fish - might be the wrong fish

```
 SELECT CONCAT("Trans ID ",TransactionID) ID
      , DateTime
      , Type Activity
      , Amount
      , 0 Payout
      , CASE WHEN Activity = "deposit" 
             THEN Amount + playerdb.CurrentBalance
             WHEN Activity IN("withdraw","bet")
             THEN 
                  CASE WHEN Payout >0 
                       THEN Payout + playerdb.CurrentBalance
                       ELSE Amount - playerdb.CurrentBalance 
                       END 
             END CurrentBalance 
   FROM transactiondb 
   LEFT 
   JOIN playerdb 
     ON transactiondb.PlayerID = playerdb.PlayerID 
  WHERE transactiondb.PlayerID = 10078 
  UNION ALL 
 SELECT CONCAT("Bet ID ",BetID)
      , DateTime
      , "Bet"
      , BetAmount
      , Payout
      , CurrentBalance 
   FROM betdb 
  WHERE PlayerID = 10078 
  ORDER 
     BY DateTime;
```

Comment: Thank you for your time reading this entry.MySql says "#1054 - Unknown column 'Activity' in 'field list'"

Comment: In field list? No, I think my field list is ok. Maybe you mistyped? Ah, but it's possible that it's referring to 'WHEN activity'. Perhaps that should be 'WHEN type'