# MySql: Using an alias in IF/IFNULL

Tags: mysql

I found this post:
[Using an Alias in SQL Calculations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077475/using-an-alias-in-sql-calculations)
which suggests you can use an alias in calculations by using

```
(select alias)
```

like:

```
SELECT 10 AS my_num, 
       (SELECT my_num) * 5 AS another_number
FROM table
```

This works fine. But now I want to use an alias in an if. So I thought it might work the same way. So I tried:

```
SELECT 10 AS my_num, 
       IFNULL(otherfield, (SELECT my_num)) AS another_number
FROM table
```

which doesn't work at all, telling me

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
near '(SELECT my_num)) AS another_number
```

Is there any way to make this work in MySql?

Comment: Works for me. What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: MySql Version 5.7.13

Answer (score 0):

No, use the entire expression directly like below unless you are accessing it in a outer query.

```
IFNULL(otherfield, 10) AS another_number
```

In your case it should be

```
SELECT 10 AS my_num, 
       IFNULL(otherfield, 10) AS another_number
FROM table
```

Comment: The problem is that my_num is of course a much more complicated calculation depending on many IFs itself. The select would be much easier to maintain if it would be possible to just re-use the alias.