# Calculating rate from two table totals SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am taking calculated totals from two different tables that are related to try and find the rate of Crime to Population.

So here is my code:

```
SELECT SUM(INCIDENT_BY_REGION.Total) AS TotalCrime, 
SUM(REGION.Population) AS TotalPopulation,
(TotalCrime/TotalPopulation) AS Rate
FROM INCIDENT_BY_REGION JOIN REGION
ON INCIDENT_BY_REGION.RegionID = REGION.RegionID;
```

But I get an error,

> Error Code 1054: Unknown Column 'TotalCrime' in 'field list

.

What I want is to find the rate of the population to crime. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using an Alias in SQL Calculations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077475/using-an-alias-in-sql-calculations)

Comment: Not a duplicate. That reusing of an Alias answer does not work.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly is not working with the given solutions in the other question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below, you should not use aliases while calculating Rate. Also, it is safer to use case-when expression whereas `sum(region.population) = 0` to avoid `divide by zero` error.:

```
SELECT SUM(INCIDENT_BY_REGION.Total) AS TotalCrime, 
SUM(REGION.Population) AS TotalPopulation,
case when SUM(REGION.Population) > 0 then 
          SUM(INCIDENT_BY_REGION.Total)/SUM(REGION.Population)
     else 0 end AS Rate
FROM INCIDENT_BY_REGION JOIN REGION
ON INCIDENT_BY_REGION.RegionID = REGION.RegionID;
```

Comment: Why recalculate the `SUM()` calls? Consider a derived table or CTE which MySQL 8.++ soon will support.

Comment: You are right, better to create a temp table, keep the calculated data there and use this table when you need to calculate rate, but for this example I don't think it will create an important performance issue, so the OP will be found what he is looking for. CTE in mysql will be awesome. @Parfait

Comment: @ErayBalkanli . . . No, Parfait is not right.  Perhaps a CTE in MySQL 8.0 would help, but the overhead of materializing the intermediate result would probably be far more expensive than just doing the sums.