# Do a mySQL search for the alias

Tags: php, mysql

How is the correct way to search for aliases?

In the code below, I am creating an alias called (USER), within this column I am gathering all the values in the column (DE) and (PARA).

```
(SELECT *, de as user FROM mensagens WHERE user = '1' GROUP BY projeto ORDER BY data DESC)
    UNION
(SELECT *, para as user  FROM mensagens WHERE user = '1' GROUP BY projeto ORDER BY data DESC)
```

SQL online: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d506b7/2

Comment: `WHERE de= '1'` Aliases are actually created at a later stage in the query process, so you cannot use them there

Comment: You can't use the alias of a column in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Yes, you can. Wrap them in  parentheses

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18020948/575376

Comment: @juergend Ooo can you show a working example in the above case please, for my education.

Comment: @juergend Thanks, do you want to put the answer for me to mark as done?

Comment: @RiggsFolly: I could not make it work. Seems aliases are only reusable in the SELECT clause but not in WHERE :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
select * from 
(
  SELECT *, de as user FROM mensagens
  UNION
  SELECT *, para FROM mensagens
) tmp
where user = 1
GROUP BY projeto 
ORDER BY data DESC
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d506b7/17)

Or even simpler:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mensagens
WHERE 1 in (de, para)
GROUP BY projeto 
ORDER BY data DESC
```