# Can I use alias name in SELECT clause?

Tags: sql

I tried it in PostgreSQL, AlaSQL, and some other RDBMSs:

```sql
SELECT 1 AS one,  1  * 2 AS two;  -- works
SELECT 1 AS one, one * 2 AS two;  -- doesn't
```

It seems that they don't support it.

#### EDIT:

As @[juergen d](https://stackoverflow.com/users/575376) mentioned in the comment:

> You can do it in MySQL: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18020948/575376

The above example shows the difference between the different RDBMSs.
This is why I ask this question.

**If ISO SQL does not guarantee such behavior, then I would try to avoid it.**
Unfortunately, it seems that some people feel that this is a useless question (probably it is, but it is important to me because I WANT TO WRITE AS PROTABLE CODE *AS POSSIBLE*).

---

So I wonder **whether it is an ISO SQL behavior**.  
It would be appreciated if links to specific reference materials are provided.

I am not asking for documentation that describes functionality that doesn't exist.
In case someone nitpicks, perhaps I should rephrase the question: **Does ISO SQL specify whether `SELECT` is executed as a whole, or can it be executed in parts?**

Comment: No, you can't do that, and the reason is pretty clear - the aliased column doesn't exist until the statement is executed. The vast majority of RDBMSs don't support it, if not all of them. You can't link to documentation that says something that says functionality does not exist - why would they document it?

Comment: @KenWhite: "*You can't link to documentation that says something that says functionality does not exist - why would they document it?*" -- I mean a piece of documentation like this: "The ISO SQL column alias does not exist until the **complete** `SELECT` clause has been executed." It does not describe functionality that does not exist, but it does explain everything.

Comment: Why would they write that documentation? I've never written software documentation that says *I'm answering this question that I never thought would be asked, just in case someone later thinks to ask it*. Have you? Did you try executing the code in your question?  Did it work? If not, what was the exact, complete error message it gave you? That error message is the official documentation. Removing the database tag is useless - if you want to know what the standard says, read it.

Comment: Sorry if that is not what you wanted. 4 of the 6 line was about PostgreSQL.  There is no "ISO SQL", only a particular version and having someone summarize all of them I would argue isn't focused.  ISO standards aren't freely available.

Comment: @KenWhite, Agian: "*It does not describe functionality that does not exist, but it does explain everything.*" ||| "*That error message is the official documentation.*" -- That error message is PostgreSQL's documentation, but I want to know what the ISO SQL says. Does it says that a `SELECT` clause is executed atomically? This is not about functionality that does not exist. ||| "*if you want to know what the standard says, read it.*" -- That's why I asked a question here.

Comment: @AllanWind "*ISO standards aren't freely available.*" -- Thanks for the information. I didn't know it before.

Comment: The alias must rely on an existing column or expression on a column.

Comment: You can do it in MySQL: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18020948/575376

Comment: @KenWhite: I updated the question. Now it should be clear enough.

Comment: Funny... I said *The vast majority of RDBMSs don't support it*, and you thank someone for pointing out what might be the single exception. ISO SQL does not guarantee that behavior - if it did, that wouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to understand if a particular SQL syntax is ISO compliant is not a simple task, for a start there are multiple versions of the standard (the latest one is 2023: https://www.iso.org/search.html?q=9075) so which version are you trying to be compliant with?

The ISO docs are also not free - the above link shows about 16 sections, each one costing about CHF200 - so to get hold of the full set would cost a significant amount of money and, even then, they are highly technical documents so the chances of most people understanding correctly how a standard would be implemented is low.

For this reason, unless you’re building a DBMS, most people don’t worry about ISO compatibility. Just keeping your SQL simple and well structured is your best guarantee that it’s portable - even if it was ISO  compliant, you’ve no guarantee that your target DBMS is compatible with (the version you’ve chosen of) the ISO standards - so being ISO compliant doesn’t equate to being portable